# python chardet can not detect utf-8 correctly

Tags: python, encode, chardet

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import chardet
s = '123'.encode('utf-8')
print(s)
print(chardet.detect(s))

ss ='编程'.encode('utf-8')
print(chardet.detect(ss))
```

and results

```
b'123'
{'encoding': 'ascii', 'confidence': 1.0, 'language': ''}
{'encoding': 'utf-8', 'confidence': 0.7525, 'language': ''}
```

Why it can not detect `s` as UTF-8?

And why is ASCII?

Is this line useless? `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`
Python newcomer, thanks!

Comment: And I learned that encode as default in python is unicode? How can I prove it? and how it affects?

Comment: Chartdet uses heuristics. **It'll always be a guess**.

Comment: And ASCII is entirely correct. ASCII is a subset of UTF-8. The first 128 characters of the Unicode standard are the same as the ASCII standard. Encoding just characters from the ASCII range to UTF-8 results in the **exacts same bytes** as encoding those same characters to ASCII.

Comment: So, '123'.encode('utf-8') means: convert string "123" which are encoded as "utf-8" to sequences of bytes.

Comment: In other words, any valid ASCII document is also a valid UTF-8 document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's just talk about these lines--all the meat is there:

```
s = '123'.encode('utf-8')
print(s)
```

You are correct that Python 3 uses Unicode by default.  When you say `'123'.encode()` you are converting a Unicode string to a sequence of bytes which will then print with the ugly `b` prefix to remind you that it is not a default type of string.

Comment: The coding part is definitely used by Python *too*: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ In Python 3 UTF-8 just happens to be the default.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Oh wow thanks for pointing that out.  That feature is so totally out of line with the Python philosophy it's hard to imagine how it got in.

Comment: Why is that out of line? Python 3 identifiers and string literals support Unicode characters, you *have* to have a method of setting an encoding for a source file.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Oh, I should have explained.  It violates "explicit is better than implicit" by using another program's comment convention (Emacs); it is also probably the first and only feature of Python which changes program semantics based on a comment.

Comment: No, read the PEP. Python *tolerates* additional information in the comment so you can re-use it for Emacs or VIM or any other editor that supports an encoding-in-a-comment setting.